# To change time format when sending from server(node) to client (react)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm struggling with dates format.

On server side which is done in Node.js I have an array of dates formatted like this:

```
["2018-05-31T22:00:00.000Z", "2018-06-14T22:00:00.000Z"]
```

What I need on the client side (React.js) is array of time formatted like that:

```
[Fri Jun 01 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST), Sat Jun 02 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)]
```

So not only time formats are different and needs to be changed but first ones are in strings, other are not (actually, what are they? ;) )

I guess the fact that both are in array is of  not much importance here I guess.

Thank you for helping

Comment: Something is processing the array and converting the string values to `Date` values (incorrectly apparently). This has to be done explicitly though, this doesn't happen magically on it's own. So either you are doing this or some library you are using. Not much we can do here to help you.

Comment: The only thing I'm doing on the node.js side is new Date(2018,05,31) and then I'm sending it to client

Comment: But something on the client converts the strings to `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the array of stringified Dates, once you have it on the client side, and convert back each String item to a Date Object.

```js
let dateString = ["2018-05-31T22:00:00.000Z", "2018-06-14T22:00:00.000Z"];
let dateObj = dateString.map( d => new Date(d) );
// done. dates Array contains now Date Objects
console.log( typeof dateObj[0] );
```

Comment: Why use map if you're modifying the array in-place? Either use `forEach`, or use `.map(d => new Date(d))` to create a new array.

Comment: my fault. fixed ;)

Comment: Uh, `map` returns a new array, which you discard, leaving the original array untouched.